# SASS to CSS compilation library

Tags: java, css, sass

Is there a Java library for compiling SASS files to CSS files on the fly? Note that build tool plugins will not work for our use case. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to do the job https://github.com/darrinholst/sass-java. Else a github search generally finds something good.